# How to create negative nunit test case for the given function using c#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-core, nunit

**Interface for Database:**

```
public interface IDatabase:
    {
        List<string> GetXmlNames(string OrderNumber);
    }
```

**Implementation for Database:**

```
 class Database: IDatabase
    {
        public List<string> GetXmlNames(string OrderNumber)
        {
            var XmlName = new List<string>();
            XmlName.Add("CustomerXmlFileName");
            XmlName.Add("GeneratedXmlFileName");

            return XmlName;
        }
    }
```

**Function to get Xml Names from Database** -
It takes order number as parameter and returns a list of string(2 Xml Names)

```
public class RetrieveXmlService
    {
        public List<string> RetrieveXmlFileName(string OrderNumber)
        {
            Database db = new Database();
            var Xmlname = db.GetXmlNames(OrderNumber);

            return Xmlname;
        }}
```

**Test Case for Positive Scenerio** -
I am sending the order number and getting the 2 Xml Names.

```
 public void RetrieveXmlFileNameTest()
        {
            var expected = new List<string>();
            expected.Add("CustomerXmlFileName");
            expected.Add("GeneratedXmlFileName");
            var mock = new Mock<ICosmosDb>();
            mock.Setup(p => p.GetXmlNamesForOrderNumber("100")).Returns(expected);
            RetrieveXmlService retrieveXmlService = new RetrieveXmlService();
            List<string> actual = retrieveXmlService.RetrieveXmlFileName("100");
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
```

**TO DO** -
How to create a Test Case for Negative Scenerio - If there is no Xml names returned from the function(null Xmlname)

Comment: `mock.Setup(p => p.GetXmlNamesForOrderNumber("-100")).Returns(null)` (or `.Returns(new List<string>())`?

Comment: ```public void RetrieveXmlFileNameTest()
        {
            var expected = new List<string>();
            var mock = new Mock<ICosmosDb>();
            mock.Setup(p => p.GetXmlNamesForOrderNumber("100")).Returns(new List<string>);
            RetrieveXmlService retrieveXmlService = new RetrieveXmlService();
            List<string> actual = retrieveXmlService.RetrieveXmlFileName("100");
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }```                                                                                   I tried this way but test case has failed

Answer (score 1):

You will struggle to unit test `RetrieveXmlService.RetrieveXmlFileName(string)` as the method is newing up "instantiating" the dependency. Regardless of how you mock your dependencies in the unit test, they will be ignored as the method you are testing is creating its own dependencies. Through Constructor Dependency Injection, as documented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), you can pass dependencies through to the class for use by the class methods.

I would amend the constructor for `RetrieveXmlService` and pass through the `IDatabase` dependency, as such

```
public class RetrieveXmlService
{
    private readonly IDatabase _db;

    public RetrieveXmlService(IDatabase db)
    {
        _db = db;      
    }

    public List<string> RetrieveXmlFileName(string OrderNumber)
    {
        var Xmlname = _db.GetXmlNames(OrderNumber);

        return Xmlname;
    }
}
```

You can then write your unit test as follows:

```
public void RetrieveXmlFileNameTest()
{
    var expected = new List<string>();
    expected.Add("CustomerXmlFileName");
    expected.Add("GeneratedXmlFileName");
    
    var mock = new Mock<IDatabase>();
    mock.Setup(p => p.GetXmlNames("100")).Returns(expected);
    RetrieveXmlService retrieveXmlService = new RetrieveXmlService(mock);
    
    List<string> actual = retrieveXmlService.RetrieveXmlFileName("100");
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

You can discover more about Dependency Injection in .NET through the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection)

Comment: I can able to test positive scenario without using constructor. For the same function I need to test a negative scenario

Comment: The positive test case passes here because you are asserting on the output of the actual implementation of `IDatabase.GetXmlNames(string)` instead of the mocked one. To prove this you can adjust the expected data in the positive test case, replace `CustomerXmlFileName` with `MyMockXmlFileName`.